# Highlight (select) district/area by tapping Google Map and get its info

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can tap on Google Maps and get district info and highlight that? Not just a point. Just like this image.

[image: just like this image]

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at documentation here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos

In short this is how you should use this feature:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=PHOTO_REFERENCE&sensor=false&maxheight=MAX_HEIGHT&maxwidth=MAX_WIDTH&key=YOUR_API_KEY

just substitute your own values in place of:

PHOTO_REFERENCE

MAX_HEIGHT - int value from 1 to 1600

MAX_WIDTH - int value from 1 to 1600

YOUR_API_KEY

and you are done

Comment: Are you sure? it gives me just a photo not any info or something like the image I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an "administrative area":

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types